# How to "use Search by Page as its own entity"?

Tags: search

Can someone clarify what sort of menu item is needed for my D6 site to be able to "use Search by Page as its own entity"?  I have SBP working -- in the sense that `/search/search_by_page/keyword` does a search and returns results, but I'm having trouble getting rid of the "Content" and "Users" tabs.  I've tried a couple of different entries in `some_random_module_menu()`, but haven't found the right one.  Any advice out there?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it suits your workflow you could just deny access to those two search pages using [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_menu_alter/6):

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['search/node']['access callback'] = FALSE;
  $items['search/user']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```

If you still need to provide access to those paths under normal circumstances, and just hide the tabs on the search-by-page page, you can provide a function for the `access callback` that does a quick check on the current URL:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['search/node']['access callback'] = 'MYMODULE_search_page_access';
  $items['search/user']['access callback'] = 'MYMODULE_search_page_access';
}

function MYMODULE_search_page_access($name) {
  // Deny access when on a search-by-page page
  if (arg(0) == 'search' && arg(1) == 'search_by_page') {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // Otherwise return the default access callback
  return _search_menu($name);
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion; that's pretty much what I've done (I used a bigger hammer and did unset($items['search/node/%menu_tail']) and unset($items['search/user/%menu_tail']);).  This, and a few other things, have gotten me going, but the question was triggered by the module authors' claim that you just needed to add something to the menu system and the old tabs would magically float away.  Like I said, I have something that works (albeit crudely), but I guess I'm still looking for the magic...  But thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% but I think that's about as magic as you're going to get...I can't think of another way to do it, certainly not one with as few lines of code as that

Comment: I've poked at this a bit more, and have decided that it's time to declare victory and move on.  Magic is highly overrated...